# Transform syntax in R

Tags: regex, r, shiny, expression-trees

Is it possible to transform expressions like this, using R:

`IF(expr.bool, expr1, expr2)` into `if (expr.bool) expr1 else expr2`

`AND(expr.bool1, expr.bool2)` (or &&) into `expr.bool1 & expr`.

`OR(expr.bool1, expr.bool2)` (or ||) into `expr.bool1 | expr.bool2`

`NOT(expr.bool)` into `!expr.bool`

`TRUE`  into `1`
`FALSE` into `0`

and so on.

I have tried the **ast** package and using substitute to build an expression tree and then adapt them to the new syntax but no one seems to work.

**What I want to do is to read an expression string using the syntax in the left, parse it and then use eval to get a float result.**

p.s. I am completely new to R.

Comment: Can you better explain why you need this? `&`, `|`, `!` are just functions, e.g., `"&"(FALSE, TRUE)` works just fine. Then you have `as.integer` and `as.numeric` or code golf alternatives such as `+(TRUE)`.

Comment: @Roland: As I explain in my last paragraph: I get (from DB) a string which is a formula using that syntax and I need to use eval to get a result, therefore I need to convert it to R syntax.

Comment: Well, the usual advice would be to avoid parsing such input ... That's why I asked for more information.

Comment: `if` is also a function, i.e., `"if"(FALSE, 1, 2)` works.

Answer (score 3):

[Everything that does something is a function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#all-calls) in R. Just do something like this:

```
IF <- `if`
IF(FALSE, 1, 2)
#[1] 2

NOT <- `!`
NOT(TRUE)
#[1] FALSE
```

Then `eval`/`parse` your strings.

Coercing logical values to integers can be done with `as.integer`.